# Why does my code have a compilation error after the else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Bear with me.

After creating the if-else statement, every time I check to see the else statement if it can go back to the menu if the string isn't true it always ends up in an error like:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

```
public class geo {
public static void main(String[] args){
byte choice = 0;
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3  = 0;
float num4 ;
double result1 = 0;
boolean quit;
String UnitofMeasurement;
String feet = "feet";
String inches = "inches";
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
while (choice != 1) {
System.out.println("\t1. Determine the perimeter of a square");
switch (choice){
  case 1:
  System.out.println("The perimeter of a square is computed 
  by multiplying the measure of one side by 4.");
            System.out.println("Enter the unit of measurement(i.e. inches/feet):");
            UnitofMeasurement = key.next();// gets the unit of measurement
            if(UnitofMeasurement.equals(feet)||UnitofMeasurement.equals(inches)){
            System.out.println("You have chosen " + UnitofMeasurement + " as the unit of measurement.");
            System.out.println("Enter the measurement of one side: ");
            num1 = key.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Side of the square: "+ format.format(num1));
            key.nextLine();
            result1 = num1 * 4;
            System.out.println("Perimeter of the square = "+ format.format(result1) +" "+  UnitofMeasurement);
            }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("Please only enter feet/inches");

                }
            enter();
            break;
```

default;

Comment: An exception message isn't a compilation error.  Also, on what line does this exception occur?

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` is telling you that you tried to convert a string to a number, and the string was `""`, so of course, it cannot be converted to number.

Comment: @rgettman 
it happens after the else statement

Answer (score 0):

If that is all the code you write your compilation errors are in `enter();` and `default;`

I think you have to implement `enter()` method in your class, and change the last error to `default:`

See this code below, without compilation errors:

```
public class geo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte choice = 0;
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        float num4;
        double result1 = 0;
        boolean quit;
        String UnitofMeasurement;
        String feet = "feet";
        String inches = "inches";
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (choice != 1) {
            System.out.println("\t1. Determine the perimeter of a square");
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("The perimeter of a square is computed by multiplying the measure of one side by 4.");
                System.out.println("Enter the unit of measurement(i.e. inches/feet):");
                UnitofMeasurement = key.next();// gets the unit of measurement
                if (UnitofMeasurement.equals(feet) || UnitofMeasurement.equals(inches)) {
                    System.out.println("You have chosen " + UnitofMeasurement + " as the unit of measurement.");
                    System.out.println("Enter the measurement of one side: ");
                    num1 = key.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Side of the square: " + format.format(num1));
                    key.nextLine();
                    result1 = num1 * 4;
                    System.out.println("Perimeter of the square = " + format.format(result1) + " " + UnitofMeasurement);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please only enter feet/inches");

                }
                break;
            default:
            }
        }
    }
}
```